# Have got some problems with sorting and rendering data with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, rendering

Have got some problems with sorting and rendering data with backbone.js
There is sorting by 'title' in comparator. 
This.model.collection has models after sorting by title, but when rendering starts models views after sorting by order.

```
    var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Todo,

    comparator: function(todo) {
        return todo.get('title');
    },

//function for sorting
    sortByDate: function () {
       this.comparator = function(todo){
           return todo.get('title');
       };
       this.sort();
    }

    });

    var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:  "li",

    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
    });
```

Comment: Where are you rendering your collection?

Comment: render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

Comment: That's your view's render method, where are you rendering your collection? That's where the sorting takes place.

Comment: The collection uses the comparator function to keep it's list of models sorted. I'm asking where you are actually rendering your collection models? Do you have a view for your collection?

Comment: No, only view for models

Comment: OK, then you need to loop through the modes in your collection (which should be sorted because of the comparator function) and render them. Generally this is done within the collection's view (I'll try and post a quick jsbin as an example shortly).

Comment: Here's a quick example http://jsbin.com/sapexamuzu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks, it's work for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that, you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark on the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) for a collection just ensures that it's models are maintained in a sorted order, if you want to render it in that order you just need to retrieve the models from the collection (most commonly this is done in your collection view) and render them.

For example in your case since you don't have a collection view you can do the following

```
todoList.each(function (todo) {
  $('#output').append(new TodoView({model: todo}).el);
});
```

Generally though, you would have this code as part of your collection view. You might also want to maintain a reference to your views so you can easily re-render or remove them. for example

```
var TodoCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    views: {}, 

    render: function () {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        this.collection.each(function (model) {
           var view = this.viewForModel(model);
           frag.appendChild(view.render().el);
        },this);

       this.$el.html(frag);
    },

    viewForModel: function (model) {
        var view;    
        if (this.views[model.cid]) {
           view = this.views[model.cid];
        } else {
           view = new TodoView({model: model});
           this.views[model.cid] = view;
        }
       return view;
    }
});
```

Here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sapexamuzu/edit?html,js,output)